# Difference of lists linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
class ObjA
{
  int ID;
  ... other properties
}

List<ObjA> listA;   // contains a list of ObjAs

List<string> listB;  // contains a list of string IDs
```

I'm trying to get a list of values that are in `listB` but are not equal to any of the `ObjA.ID`property in listA.

Comment: this will make for some good reading in your spare time to understand Generics, Linq / Lambda expressions - http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/08/17/linq-lambda-expression-iequalitycomparer-for-ienumerable-distinct-and-except/

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I definitely need a lot of work on Linq and Lambda expressions.

Comment: not a problem.. this becomes quite useful once you get use to the power behind linq's extension methods

Comment: This guy always explains things very clearly: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL90AF0EFFEF782D27

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
listB.Except(listA.Select(o => o.ID.ToString()))
```